# Why does model with hyperparameter tuning underperform?

Tags: predictive-modeling

I have a dataset where I applied xgb model with grid search to tune the hyperparameters and class balancing. I compared the model without any hyperparameter tuning with a model that has been applied with hyperparameter tuning. The model without any hyperparameters set output an accuracy around 90 (train), 81 (test) but with parameters, it has an accuracy of 70 (train) 69 (test). Hyperparameters: n_estimators, max_depth, eta, gamma, L1 and L2 regularization, scale_pos_weight. May I know why does the model has not improve? Despite around 10% difference for the model without any hyperparameters on train and test accuracy, I think that it should not be an issue on overfitting.

Comment: Could you add more info to your questions, such as some code or the hyperparameters?

Comment: It would be a good idea to observe a confusion matrix (instead of only accuracy) if the data is imbalanced.